# Installing Pygame on OS X Mavericks with Python 3.3

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Is there any way to get Pygame to install on Mavericks with Python 3.3?  When I ran the installation package, it said it must install on a disk where Python 2.7 is the system default. 2.7 actually is the system default on my computer and I use 3.3 in IDLE.  So I thought it would be able to install, but it won't let me continue with the installation.

Comment: I am getting this exact issue - it is driving me crazy, if I install pygame through other means it just install onto the OS X 2.7 version and NOT my 3.3

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

Download and install XQuartz: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Using the [homebrew packaging manager for OSX](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew tap homebrew/headonly

brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi

brew install --HEAD smpeg
```

Install Mercurial (it's the VCS that pygame maintainers use):

```
brew install hg
```

Activate the virtualenv for your Python 3.3 (or prefix the following call to pip with the prefix to Py 3.3 e.g. `/usr/local/bin/pip`).

Install PyGame from its repo using pip:

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```